# Cron does not execute a python script that needs a python3 module in AWS-ec2

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-ec2, module, cron

I tried to make a cron job on crontab which runs a python script on AWS ec2. My python script includes a module that is only available for python3. 
Using the following command I changed the ec2 default python interpreter from python2.7 to python3.4 
Source /home/ec-2user/venv/python34/bin/activate
and then using pip install, I installed the required module for python3.4. So now the default interpreter is python3.4 and when I run the script on ec2-user directory using the following command:
python test.py
the program runs without any problem (so I am sure the module is installed correctly).
But when I assign python file to a cronjob
* * * * * python test.py

It does not work. Checking the mail, the error is:
“No module found named “xxxxx” “

But as I said it worked fine outside of the cron.

I was wondering if you can help me with this problem. I appreciate your time and information.

Answer (score 3):

You have to make a shell script which will do the steps of changing to script directory, activating virtual environment and then running it.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd $YOUR_DIR
. venv/bin/activate
python3.4 test.py
```

Then you call this script in cron with
`/bin/bash /.../script.sh`

---

What you could do additionally is

`chmod +x test.py`

and add/update first line to:

`#!/usr/bin/env python3.4`

This way you can just run Python script with `./test.py`

Comment: thanks alot for your explanation. It solved my problem perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Create file as 'user_cron.sh'

```
#!/bin/bash
cd '/root/my_new_project_python'
. my_project_venv/bin/activate
python3 main.py
```

set the cron using crontab -e